# Angular: How to data-bind an async property to a background image

Tags: angular, data-binding

- I'm trying to set a background image on a div with angular.

  - The 'image.imagrURL | async' works well when just assigning it to a plain 'img' tag.
  - The issue I'm having is when trying to assign it to an inline background image

The question is: How do I modify my below snippet to work? :)

**HTML**

```html
 <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image.imageurl | async  + ')'}">
```

**Error**

> Parser Error: Missing expected }

I'm not entirely sure where that's supposed to go.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding brackets will be helped, because you are trying call async pipe on `'url(' + image.imageurl`

Try in this way:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (image.imageurl | async)  + ')'}">
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Please note that the application might request for 'null' or 'undefined' from server if this element gets loaded before the async task resolved; which is quite likely to occur. 

Consider adding special *ngIf syntax introduced with Angular 4. That is:
<div 
*ngIf="image | async; let image; else loading"
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (image.imageurl | async)  + ')'}"></div>
<template #loading>Image is Loading...</template>